# Upgrading from Fedora-27 to Fedora-28

Tags: fedora, upgrade, dist-upgrade

At the moment I am running `fedora-27` and I would like to upgrade it to `fedeora-30`. I followed the steps described in [fedora wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/DNF_system_upgrade).

1. `sudo dnf upgrade --refresh`
2. `sudo dnf install dnf-plugin-system-upgrade`
3. `sudo dnf system-upgrade download --refresh --best --allowerasing --releasever=28`
4. `sudo dnf system-upgrade reboot`

Note that I tried to gradually upgrade to the next release instead of upgrading directly to `fedora-30`, since from previous experience (i.e. when wanting to upgrade from `fedora-24` to `fedora-27`) I've found out that it was smoother.

After performing the `dnf system-upgrade reboot` command, my laptop rebooted, the upgrade screen when on and eventually I was booted again in `fedora-27` while there is not `fedora-28` option on the boot menu.

These are the steps that I followed to understand what's going wrong :

1. I had a look after @DavidYockey 's suggestion to `/boot` in case there is something related to `f28` but there is nothing there as well. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lgx33.png). I also checked the `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` file and there isn't any entry related to `f28` (https://pastebin.com/Z81uJ0gr). So I guess that this means, it's not realated to `grub`.
2. I checked with `journalctl -r -p err` but I couldn't see something helpful there, either apart from the following entry which doesn't specify why it failed to upgrade. (https://pastebin.com/dnaDHcAQ)

   > systemd[1](https://cernbox.cern.ch/index.php/s/CuoPu8HxLmGr9rJ): Failed to start System Upgrade using DNF.
3. I then, had a look at the `dnf.log` file, which can be found [here](https://cernbox.cern.ch/index.php/s/CuoPu8HxLmGr9rJ). I saw some critical errors [there](https://pastebin.com/N7EaUiDW), but I am not sure what to do. For example

   > 2019-06-28T05:43:26Z CRITICAL Error opening file for checksum: /var/lib/dnf/system-upgrade/fedora-f21308f6293b3270/packages/compat-libicu57- 
   >   57.1-2.fc28.x86_64.rpm
   >
   > 2019-06-28T05:43:26Z CRITICAL Package "compat-libicu57-57.1-2.fc28.x86_64" 
   >   from repository "fedora" has incorrect checksum
4. I run `sudo dnf repolist all` and it seems that some repositories are disabled 
   [image]
   I am wondering how can I enable them; maybe I can't.
5. I enabled the disabled repositories by editing the `.repo` files in `/etc/yum.repos.d` and changing the value of `enable` to `1` in the cases where it was `0` and then repeated `sudo dnf upgrade --refresh`, `sudo dnf system-upgrade download --refresh --best --allowerasing --releasever=28` and `sudo dnf system-upgrade reboot`. Still the `dnf.log` gives me the same critical error seen in 3.

Any idea what to do next in order to eventually upgrade to `fedora-30`?

Comment: Just a thought... Maybe an entry for F28 just didn't get added to grub. Are there F28 files in /boot?

Comment: You're probably aware of this, but for the benefit of anyone else reading... Upgrading from an end-of-life release, like F27, "is a less-tested and less-supported operation. You can try to upgrade" a couple of ways as described. (https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/DNF_system_upgrade#Can_I_upgrade_from_an_End_of_life_release.3F) To me, it reads like there are no guarantees.

Comment: @DavidYockey : Thank you very much for your comment. There is nothing in `/boot` or `/boot/grub2` related to `f28` ( https://imgur.com/e192pbx ). There is also nothing in the `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` file. So this means that it's not related to booting, which is an information! Thanks! Any idea on what might be the issue?

Comment: I'm a bit wary of suggesting too much and making things worse because I lack experience fixing broken version upgrades (I just restore from a clone and restart if something goes wrong). But a thought did cross my mind... Maybe dnf's mucked up, and maybe running `dnf clean all` would help?

Comment: @DavidYockey : I have found a solution. It seems that the `dnf clean all` didn't help. The problem was a corrupted file (see my answer)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the `compat-libicu57- 57.1-2.fc28.x86_64.rpm` file which was saved in

`/var/lib/dnf/system-upgrade/fedora-f21308f6293b3270/packages/`

The **critical error** that was encountered was referring to an **incorrect checksum**.
To solve the issue the following steps were followed

1. The `/var/lib/dnf/system-upgrade/fedora-f21308f6293b3270/packages/compat-libicu57- 57.1-2.fc28.x86_64.rpm` file was deleted
2. I downloaded the `compat-libicu57- 57.1-2.fc28.x86_64.rpm` file from [rmpfind.net](https://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/fedora/28/x86_64/c/compat-libicu57-57.1-2.fc28.x86_64.html)
3. I moved the downloaded `.rpm` file to `/var/lib/dnf/system-upgrade/fedora-f21308f6293b3270/packages/`
4. I then run `sudo dnf system-upgrade reboot` and the system was upgraded to `f28`